# Nakayama lemma Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I already know the following version of Nakayama´s Lemma:

Let $R$ be a ring and $I \subseteq R$ an ideal in the Jacobson-Radical of $R$. If $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module with $IM=M$, then $M=0$.

I want to deduce the following more general version from the above version:

Let $R$ be a ring and $I\subseteq R$ an ideal. If $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module with $IM=M$, then there exists an element $i \in I$, s.t. $im=m$ for all $m \in M$.

I looked at the localization $S^{-1}M$ with $S=\{1+i: i \in I\}$ and followed from the first version of Nakayama´s lemma, that $S^{-1}M=0$. But from there, I could only show that for all $m\in M$, there exists an $ i \in I$, s.t. $im=m$.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have established that for all $m\in M$, there exists some $a_m\in I$ such that $(1-a_m)m=0$. Now write $M=Rm_1+\cdots+Rm_s$. Then it is easy to see that $b=(1-a_{m_1})\cdots(1-a_{m_s})$ annihilates $M$. Finally, notice that $b=1-i$ for some $i\in I$.